# how to import data from 2 table(parent and child table)?-informatica

Tags: transformation, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I tried the SQ and linked directly from source to SQ only the required columns and generated workflow but it shows no result.
Do I have to use any other transformation or do I have to add query in SQ if so how?
help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific where you are facing the problem? Also let us know if you are getting any error.

Comment: Have you specified the join condition in SQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution no need to use join transformation since they are in parent child relationship. 
with my previous workflow it didn't show any error, executed fine but the issue is it didn't read any data from source tables hence  no rows are inserted into target table

all I did is ,I jus specified the join condition in SQ itself now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Parent Table To Source Qualifier(Parent) & Child Table To Source Qualifier(Child)

Next,
Join both Source qualifiers based on a join condition using Join Transform
(or) 
If you want to Union both data sets then use Union transoform

Next,
Use expression transform for cleaning,filtering data or to apply any logic

Last,
Map the expression transform to load the Target table